# printing taxonomy and meta fields values

Tags: archives, meta-value

I have the following code in order to print the post ID in a certain point of the archive page. In the same line I'd like to print other meta data, better to say an icon and than the corrispondent meta data, i.e: icon of n of guests and the the number of guests (taxonomy), icon of the beach and then the number of meters of the distance from the beach (number custom field), which is the best solution?

```
<div class="article-content clearfix">

    <?php
    if ( get_post_format() ) :
        get_template_part( 'inc/post-formats' );
    endif;

    echo "codice alloggio: ",get_the_ID(),colormag_colored_category();
    ?>
```